# Mutual SSL vs. Token-based auth

Tags: security, authentication, ssl

I am working on a web application and security is one of our main concerns in this application. I was looking at different methods of API security (mentioned here on [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Anti-farming)) and couldn't understand the difference between Mutual SSL auth and token-based auth. Here is a brief into of both before I move forward,

> Mutual (or two-way) SSL authentication provides a combination of an encrypted data stream, mutual authentication of both server and client, and automatic sign-in convenience.

[Source](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_mutual_about.htm)

> Every single request will require the token. This token should be sent in the HTTP header so that we keep with the idea of stateless HTTP requests.

[Source](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication)

From what I get, they both are probably alternatives of each other, so here are a few question that I have in mind and if you could answer them, I'd be so thankful.

- In my opinion, both of these methods are alternatives of each other, is it so?
- Yes? Then which one is better then the other and why?
- No? Then should we use one of these or both? Also, whats the difference between them based on which you're saying that they are different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In my opinion, both of these methods are alternatives of each other,
>   is it so?

Both of these method should be used based on your context. Two methods are used based on the need and security context.

> No? Then should we use one of these or both? Also, whats the
>   difference between them based on which you're saying that they are
>   different.

**Token-based auth** (OAuth) usually used in a scenario where there is a need to establish a secure communication between mobile app/ web app and api server.Where password is not stored in the device.It store a temporary token to the device which expire over time.

**Mutual SSL** Mutual Authentication can be good candidate for establish a secured communication between two servers.

So it is the context which decide the choice!